# how to keep track of planning variable assignment in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner, drools-planner, planning

Is there a way to access planning variable's assignment during planning?

In my use case, I want to assign a planning variable with certain status only one time only during planning. After that I don't want to use that planning variable.

I know that in optaplanner, a planning variable/problem fact can not change, so i can not change its status.

Is there a way to get list of planning variable assignment during planning so that in java code or drools file, i can avoid re-assignment if it has been used once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use a hard constraint to enforce that.**

Yes, you could use MoveFilters too, but that's not a good idea because sometimes you need to break hard constraints to escape local optima.

Comment: thanks for replying. I'd also like to implement it as a hard constraint in drools file but how do I access this information in drools file. 
Let's say i have following scenario:
**Planning entity** : F1, F2
**Planning variable**: v1, v2. I want to use v1 only once.


Now if planner randomly assigns v1 to F1, how do i access this information to write a hard constraint so that v1 is not assigned to F2 ?

Comment: See the score rule "2 talks in same room at the same time" in conference scheduling example

Comment: thanks a lot for help @Geoffrey!
I end up implementing it as an accumulate function in drools file. I check if sum of  usage of a planning variable is more than one then a hard constraint is violated.

Comment: thats sub-efficient to check conflicts. Accumulates are much slower score calculation speed wise than doing `when Talk($f: foo, $id : id) Talk(foo == $f, id > $id) then -1hard end`

Comment: That's helpful information, I have changed it as you suggested. Using accumulate I was getting hard constraint violation even though i have enough resources but it wasn't using all of them (I am not sure why). After changing it as per your suggestion, it works perfectly. Thank you!!